# How can i Identify php-cgi scripts which are consuming CPU on my server

Tags: php, apache

I have a lot of `php-cgi` from `http` apache when I do a `ps auxw`

I don't know which website/scripts is taking on my cpu.

With a pstree i see that it's apache:

```
 |-httpd-+-16*[httpd]
 |       `-6*[httpd---php-cgi]
```

How can i identify it?

Thanks alls

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I believe this question is more suited to ServerFault.com, since this is more a server issue than a programming problem. If you believe it isn't suitable there, you should post on SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com. This website is for programming issues and other questions directly related with code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
ps eax |grep php |grep -v grep|awk '{print $1 $8}'
```

You can change `$1` and `$8` and add other values that you need `$1` in my system gives me the pid (you can use to kill it) and the script running.

Answer (score 0):

Once identifying a PID that is drawing CPU recourses, you can replace "PID" in the command below with the PID that you wish to investigate.

```
pstree -H PID
```

In order to highlight that process and its ancestors in the tree. 
you may also wish to add the -a argument to pstree in order to see which command is running that process. Again, replace "PID" with the actual PID.

```
pstree -H PID -a
```

Comment: That doesn't add what?

Comment: |-httpd-+-121*[httpd---php-cgi]
     |       `-13*[httpd]                                                                                            it doesn t add any information: pstree -H 1886